how to improve Firefox' Tree Style Tabs' CSS for multiline tabs?
Jusy as the title says: how to improve Firefox' Tree Style Tabs' CSS for multiline tabs?
The relevant part of the custom CSS that TST allows you to specify is:
/*multi line tabs*/
tab-item {
  max-height: 4em !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  text-align:top;
}
tab-item tab-label {
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
  text-align:top;
  white-space: wrap !important;
  display: inline !important;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;  
}

Their suggested CSS as can be seen here does seem to be enough.
The most I've achieved with the aforementioned CSS looks like thisl I would like to limit the text to 3 lines and keep readability:


What about -webkit-line-clamp?
/*multi line tabs*/
tab-item {
  max-height: 4em !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  text-align:top;
}
tab-item tab-label {
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
  text-align:top;
  white-space: wrap !important;
  display: -webkit-inline-box !important;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;  
}



Not perfect, but good enough. Thanks. (the last tab seem to have issues; also it would be great if the height was dynamic.... apart from that, could you hide the scrollbar completely?)

I ended up building on @Jordan Mann's answer.
Here is what I came up with:

** removing height:auto recovers all tabs **, before last tabs were not being shown
2 lines per tab is enough
adjusted label's margin per tab.

This is perfect for me :-)
/*multi line tabs*/
tab-item {
  /*max-height: 4em !important;*/
  overflow: hidden !important;
  /*border: 1px solid red;*/ /*for debugging....*/
  /*margin: 5px;*/ /*for debugging....*/
  /*text-align:top;*/
  /*height: auto;*/
  margin-left:3px;
}
tab-item tab-label {
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
  text-align:top;
  white-space: wrap !important;
  display: -webkit-inline-box !important;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

